# Invoice validation batch processing

Tags: apache-spark, wso2, batch-processing, wso2-das

I am doing a project for invoice validation with 2 million of lines of products, I must be validate price range, duplicate lines, customer plans, match between customer gender and product, etc. and put validation result (what lines are bad and the reason) in a database or a file.

I want know if in this kind of project we can use **wso2 DAS** batch processing (or **spark** directly) to process this validation over invoice file or if batch processing is for other kinds of projects.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: How many gigs of data are these 2 million lines?  My gut is telling me that Spark may be overkill for your problem.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the help. At this moment the 2 o 2,5 millons of lines are 1 Gigabyte of information, but this file can be more large because the number of customers grow every month.

Comment: Please note that there are more input files involved to make that validations: a file with detailed customer information (about 2 million customers), a file with product information, file with sales price ranges, etc